# Получить класс PhoneStatusBar

Tags: java, android

Добрый день.

Мне нужно получить класс PhoneStatusBar.
Пишу так:

```
    try
    {
        Class<?> classPhoneStatusBar = Class.forName("com.android.systemui.statusbar.phone.PhoneStatusBar");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
    {
        Log.d("D", "ClassNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
    }
```

Но получаю ошибку, что такой класс не найден, хотя такой класс точно есть https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/6023c0d8d269f056508ff7cba1b6d546091853b0/packages/SystemUI/src/com/android/systemui/statusbar/phone/PhoneStatusBar.java